# Why the url is undefined in $_GET array?

Tags: php

Just before I hit this error, I was getting the '`url`' from $_GET array. But now I get this error => `Notice: Undefined index: url`

I learnt from other sources that if the page is called directly like mydomain.index.php could hit this error.

But I'm not calling directly like so, why do I get this error? Now I only added this few lines for debugging, why would still the 'url' be undefined?

the url in the browser=> `http://localhost/mysite/index/`

I should get `index` as url. I noticed that, anything apart from index is typed, can return the url. Only when index is typed, it says url is undefined.

```
<?php

echo $_GET['url'];
exit;
```

.htaccess (just incase this influence the error)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what are you expecting back? Url is rightly undefined..

Comment: it should give me 'index' as url

Comment: no it shouldn't - you've not define url as $_GET variable anywhere in your script.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs — Pay attention to the mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: What't the purpose of the first rewrite rule, does your installation really need that?

Comment: just a wild guess, but it might have something to with `MultiViews` in conjunction with the `RewriteCond` rule; as `index.php` _does_ exist it might just not rewrite at all

Comment: @Quentin weird I have similar .htaccess and not once accessed it without first declaring it but I can remove comments if not worth being here :)

Comment: @jeroen, I'm developing mvc framework. For that I need all request to eb handled from index.php

Comment: That's what the second rule does, what do you need `RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]` for?

Comment: What did you change just before it broke?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/44780583/mysite/index/

Comment: @jeroen, QSA means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite (olle?p=1 will be rewritten as index.php?url=olle&p=1

Comment: @Capsule, I changed the path for the controller..before it broke

Comment: I know that, what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: @Quentin, when I type this in the browser url, http://localhost/mysite/?url=index, no error. Only when http://localhost/mysite/index/ is typed the error occur.What does that mean. rtrim doesn't help.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_GET['url'];
exit;
?>
```

for example if your page is http://localhost/index.php?url=11 here the first echo statement will echoing index.php?url=11 and the second echoing 11 
$_GET global variable treat every thing after the "?" not the the path of your page

Comment: For me I consider the result "Notice: Undefined index: url" why my answer voted down if it is not the case

Comment: You appear to have completely ignored the mod_rewrite aspect of the question.